# How to apply a condition only when multiple rows are retrieved in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

My apologies, I am new to SQL Server queries. I am joining two SQL Server tables in my query. This may produce either a single or multiple rows. Currently, I am selecting the top row by using `TOP 1`.

I want to select the row, if there is more than one row retrieved, where `ci.CLOCK_OUT_TIME` is NULL. The following is my query, I am not sure how to incorporate the `ci.CLOCK_OUT_TIME is NULL` condition only when the query pulls multiple rows.

If it pulls just one row, the `ci.CLOCK_OUT_TIME is NULL` condition should not be applied. I tried to use coalesce function, but it didn't give the desired result.

```
SELECT TOP 1 
    ps.PLANNED_SCHEDULE_ID, ps.SHIFT_ID, 
    ps.EMPLOYEE_ID,
    SCHEDULE_SOURCE, ps.JOB_ID, ps.[START_DATE], ps.END_DATE, 
    ps.START_TIME, ps.END_TIME, 
    ps.STORE_ID, ps.OVERTIME_MINUTES, ps.REGULAR_MINUTES 
FROM 
    PLANNED_SCHEDULE ps WITH (NOLOCK) 
LEFT JOIN 
    CLOCK_IN ci ON ci.PLANNED_SCHEDULE_ID = ps.PLANNED_SCHEDULE_ID 
WHERE 
    DATEDIFF(DAY, ps.START_DATE, '11/3/2018') = 0  
    AND EMPLOYEE_ID = '2211'  
ORDER BY 
    CAST(ps.start_date + ' ' + ps.start_time AS DATETIME)
```

Comment: Please add sample input and output data to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just order by `ci.CLOCK_OUT_TIME` if you have multiple rows and some of those are null will be on the top.

```
ORDER BY 
    CAST(ps.start_date + ' ' + ps.start_time AS DATETIME),
    ci.CLOCK_OUT_TIME
```

**[SQL DEMO](https://rextester.com/MCC17211)**